# Problems reading MongoDb collection with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have problems reading this collection with mongoose and Node.js:

[image: I have one JSON inside mi Collection]

I have one JSON inside my Collection and i try to read this with this code:

```
materias.find().exec(function(err1,materias){
        if(err1){console.log(err1); return next();}
        for(x=0;x<materias.length;x++){
            //console.log(materias[x].Nombre);
            //var arreglo=materias[x].Horario[0].Dia; // TRY ONE
            var arreglo=JSON.parse(materias[x].Horario[0]); // TRY TWO
            console.log(arreglo[0]);

        }
         //RESPONSE TRY ONE
         console.log(arreglo) UNDEFINED
         //RESPONSE TRY TWO
         undefined [ 
         //if I use JSON.stringify the response is {[object][object]...
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you edit and add the error you get?

Comment: You don't need to manually parse the `JSON` when using mongoose as it does that for you. What error does it produce?

Comment: I put the responses in the post, mongoose respond me with [object][object] then,  I need to parse the the object?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse `JSON` manually with mongoose.

You get `undefined` because you define variable `arreglo` inside the loop but try to access it outside of it. This should work:

```
materias.find().exec(function(err1,materias){
if(err1){console.log(err1); return next();}
for(x=0;x<materias.length;x++)  {        
    var arreglo = materias[x].Horario[0]; // TRY TWO
    console.log(arreglo);   
}
```

Comment: What is '[[' in the response?

Comment: is part of the array, I think Mongoose respond me with one String: [[object],[object]] but this isn't an array

Comment: Try logging the properties of `materias[x]`

Comment: console.log(materias[x].Nombre) Response: Tópicos Selectos de Programación
console.log(materias[x].Horario);Response: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], is an object, so i need to use JSON.parse :C

Comment: It's not an object, it's an array of objects and you don't need to parse them. `materias[x].Horario[0].Dia` should work

Comment: not working :c console.log(materias[x].Horario[0].Dia); Response: Undefined :'( console.log(materias[x].Horario.Dia[0]) Response: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

What i suppose the error is: you have database named as materias and you are using the same name for the returned collection. Try changing the return name collection to something other.

materias.find().exec(function(err1,**change_name_here**){

//required code
}

Answer (score 0):

FINALYYYYYYYYYY i fixed it changing my mongoose model
I had this:

```
var materias=new Schema({
    Nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    Docente:{type:String, required:true},
    Horario:{type:String, required:true}

});
module.exports = materias;
```

and change for this:

```
Horario:[{Dia:String, Hora:String, Tiempo:String}]
```

for reading:

```
for(x=0;x<materias.length;x++){
                var arreglo=materias[x].Horario; // TRY TWO
                console.log(arreglo[0].Dia);

            }
```